# asp.net ajax beginrequest

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm creating an asp.net application and I need to get the name of the control who initiated an asynchronous post pack from a `beginRequestHandler`.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginAjaxRequest);
    }

    function beginAjaxRequest(sender, args) {
       // do work here
    }

</script>
```

Comment: And your question is? What is not working? What have your tried?

Comment: i'm just looking for the name of the sender, i'm using vs 2005 and autocompletion for javascript does't work, so i can't now the right property to get the name of the control how send the asyn post back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the postbackelement

```
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
     var elem = args.get_postBackElement();
     alert(args.get_postBackElement().id);
}
```